# Jquery Draggable save position, different ID's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to get this double click, drag and drop and then save to local storage to work anyone got a brilliant idea?

```
<img ondblclick="init (this.id)" src="http://images.dailytech.com/nimage/G_is_For_Google_New_Logo_Thumb.png" id="goog" class="icons">
<img ondblclick="init (this.id)" src="http://images.dailytech.com/nimage/G_is_For_Google_New_Logo_Thumb.png" id="glo" class="icons">
<img ondblclick="init (this.id)" src="http://images.dailytech.com/nimage/G_is_For_Google_New_Logo_Thumb.png" id="g" class="icons">
```

```
var sPositions = localStorage.positions || "{}",
    positions = JSON.parse(sPositions);

$.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos)
})

function init (id) {

    $("#" + id).draggable({
        grid: [ 15, 15 ], 
        stop: function (event, ui) {
           positions[this.id] = ui.position
           localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
        }
    })
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caa888/Lyfqwj1c/8/

thanks

Comment: What should it do? explanation of it's purpose...

Comment: Syntax error `grid: [ 15, 15 ];`, remove the `;` and use `,` there